# new mongo/client does not regonsie findandmodify

Tags: php, mongodb

So I am, not sure if I am doing something wrong of if findandmodify is not part of 
the mongo/client

here is the code I am using

```
try {
                $retval = $db->findAndModify(
                        array("uid"=>New MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($_SESSION["ipet_user"]),"data"=>array("url" => $data["picture"]["data"]["url"])),
                        array('$set' => array("data"=>
                                    array("url" => $data["picture"]["data"]["url"],"type"=> "facebook/image",
                                    "date"=>new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime())
                                ,
                                "uid"=>New MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($_SESSION["ipet_user"])
                            )),
                        null,
                        array(
                             "sort" => array("priority" => -1),
                             "new" => true,
                     )
                );
            } catch(MongoResultException $e) {
                echo $e->getCode(), " : ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                var_dump($e->getDocument());
            }
```

Comment: The new PHPLib (I assume you are using) actually does not have a findandmodify, it is now split into many differetn functions

Comment: For reference, here are the functions https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Collection.php#L562

Comment: @Sammaye I am using <?php

.

Infact I am using the mongodb php that MongoDB recommends for their Atless software. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#php-driver-example

Comment: @Sammaye I just posted a new little off toipic but not totally - it at the end of the day relates to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604329/mongodb-atlas-and-php